# Spring session handling: HttpSessionDestroyedEvent not received

Tags: spring, session, web-applications

I have a web app where in the `web.xml` I have added the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` as listener. The web app runs on Jetty 7.x and we are using Spring 3.1.1.

This is supposed to fire `HttpSessionCreatedEvent` and `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` to Spring context event listeners.

I have a Bean (`@Controller`) that implements `ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent>`. `ApplicationEvent` is the common parent class of `HttpSessionCreatedEvent` and `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent`. When I now login to my web application or log out from it I'd expect these events to be fired to the `onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event)` method. I have received other events like some request handling event, but the expected event's didn't show up. I have traced the app a bit, the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` definitely fires the event to the context, but the listener isn't approached. what do I miss here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `HttpSessionEventPublisher` publishes events on the "Spring Root WebApplicationContext" per the javadoc, this is the application context registered through `ContextLoaderListener` entry in your web.xml file. Your @Controller on the other hand is probably registered through a different application context altogether - the one registered through the DispatcherServlet. So I would suggest that you create a different ApplicationListener, register it to the Root WebapplicationContext, the events should come through then.

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar problem, if it not possible to move your ApplicationListener to the root context, you can use the org.springframework.security.context.DelegatingApplicationListener.

Just autowire a DelegatingApplicationListener in your Bean and use constructor / @PostConstruct to register your listener against the DelegatingApplicationListener (one should be already in place by spring-security)