# How Do I Use SessionDestroyedEvent?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am having a problem trying to get my SessionDestroyedEvent to work.  I want it to print out whenever the session times out.  I am clearing my history to force it to time out.

This is my code:

```
@Service
public class MyTimeoutFilter implements
        ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent>
{
    public MyTimeoutFilter()
    {
        super();
        System.out.println("Application context listener is created!");
    }

    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event)
    {
        if (event instanceof SessionDestroyedEvent)
        {
            SessionDestroyedEvent sdEvent = (SessionDestroyedEvent) event;

            List<SecurityContext> lstSecurityContext = sdEvent
                    .getSecurityContexts();

            for (SecurityContext securityContext : lstSecurityContext)
            {
                System.out.println("Security Context: "
                    securityContext.getAuthentication().getName());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("This is a test.");
    }
}
```

All I get is "Application context listener is created.", followed by "This is a test."  I never have the code inside the if statement run.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I don't have a file called "application-context.xml".  I do however have a "servlet-context.xml" and a "security-context.xml".  Here is both:

Servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<annotation-driven />

<resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.blahblahblah.bagbox" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:jdbc.properties" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven />
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="order">
        <beans:value>1</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}" p:user="${app.jdbc.username}" p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
    p:acquireIncrement="5" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60" p:maxPoolSize="100"
    p:maxStatements="50" p:minPoolSize="10" />

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

</beans:beans>
```

Here is my Security-context.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
    entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*"
        access="isAnonymous()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout*"
        access="isAnonymous()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/"
        access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <security:anonymous />
    <security:custom-filter ref="loginFilter"
        position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER"
        ref="logoutFilter" />
</security:http>

<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.html" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="loginFilter"
    class="com.blahblahblah.bagbox.security.filter.MyLoginFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler"
        ref="failureHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        ref="successHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="successHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="failureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/loginFailed.html" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="logoutFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="/login.html" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean id="securityContextLogoutHandler"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
            <beans:bean id="logoutHandler"
                class="com.blahblahblah.bagbox.security.filter.MyLogoutHandler" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout.html" />
</beans:bean>

<security:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" />

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:ref local="bindAuthenticator" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:ref local="authoritiesPopulator" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="userDetailsContextMapper" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="bindAuthenticator"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="initialDirContextFactory" />
    <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authoritiesPopulator"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="initialDirContextFactory" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="" />
    <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn" />
    <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
    <beans:property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsContextMapper"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPersonContextMapper" />

<beans:bean id="userSearch"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1"
        value="(sAMAccountName={0})" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2"
        ref="initialDirContextFactory" />
    <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="initialDirContextFactory"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg
        value="ldap://ccpdc.countrycurtains.local:389/dc=countrycurtains,dc=local" />
    <beans:property name="userDn"
        value="CN=LDAP BIND,CN=Users,DC=countrycurtains,DC=local" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="ld4pb1nd" />
    <beans:property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="java.naming.referral">
                <beans:value>follow</beans:value>
            </beans:entry>
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="loggerListener"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener" />

</beans:beans>
```

Can someone who has a lot of experience with SessionDestroyedEvent and/or getting session timeouts to work with Spring Security please help me.  All of the code I have looked up on Google points me to methods that are no longer valid (such as getSecurityContext(), when it has been changed to getSecurityContexts()).

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to declare `HttpSessionEventPublisher` in `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Also I don't quite understand how clearing your history should force session to time out. If you want to test session timeout functionality you need to configure some small session timeout in `web.xml` (for example, 1 minute), log in and wait until it times out.

Comment: I changed the last line to System.out.println(event.getClass().toString());  I get a whole long list of "class org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletRequestHandledEvent" but no "SessionDestroyed".

Comment: @snowfi6916: Are you sure that session actually gets destroyed?

Comment: @ axtavt I added the session timeout to the web.xml and set it to 1 minute.  After one minute, it takes me back to my login page.  So I'm pretty sure the session is getting destroyed.

Comment: You have to use **servlets version 3+**... Spent 2 bloody days. :/

Answer (score 3):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810153/spring-session-handling-httpsessiondestroyedevent-not-received) may solve your problem.

HttpSessionEventPublisher and your service class both has to be under "Spring Root WebApplicationContex".

Comment: Would you be able to provide the code on how to do that Ketan?  I Googled for it but I found nothing about it.

Comment: Can you share your application context xml files?

Comment: I don't have an application-context.xml file, but I do have a servlet-context.xml and a security-context.xml file that I just added to my original post.

Comment: Here is the issue: If your 'MyTimeoutFilter' class (bean) is instantiated by servlet-context.xml file (Servlet ApplicationContext), it is not going to receive 'SessionDestroyedEvent'. It has to be instantiated by root-context.xml (Spring Root WebApplicationContext) defined in your web.xml file.  This is what is described in the link that I gave you.

Comment: Ketan, I instantiated it in the root-context.xml.  I am now getting the class org.springframework.context.event.HttpSessionDestroyedEvent when I run the onApplicationEvent method, which is good.  However, nothing in my if statement runs, so it is not detecting my "event instanceof HttpSessionDestroyedEvent".  Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Can you explain:  I am now getting the class org.springframework.context.event.HttpSessionDestroyedEvent when I run the onApplicationEvent method? Just print which events you are receiving in 'MyTimeoutFilter' class? If you are receiving that event in your class, it should go through if statement.